# Android Wear Application ID Not Changed

Tags: android, wear-os, package-name

When I started developing my Android Wear companion app I was unaware that the package name had to be exactly the same in order to connect. So instead of naming it `com.example.myapp`, I named it `com.example.wear`. I subsequently found out that both package names must be the same, so I changed the companion's package name to `com.example.myapp`.

But I am still having trouble to get them to connect. I also noticed that when I try to uninstall the app using the command `adb -s emulator-5554 com.example.myapp`, the uninstall fails, but when I use the old package name (`com.example.wear`) it succeeds. So the application ID never actually changed.

I found in Module Settings, under the 'Flavors' tag, there is a field for `Application ID`. The name here was still the old package name, so I changed it to the new one as well, yet the problem still persists. I have already done a decent amount of work, and I would rather not start over from an older build. Has anyone else ran into this problem? Is there a solution?

**EDIT:** I have also tried setting `applicationId 'com.example.myapp'` under `android { defaultConfig { } }` in the the `build.gradle` file. Nothing has changed.

Comment: Have you updated your Manifest file with the new package name? I am not sure what you exactly did when you said you changed the companion's package name to ****; did you mean you made the change in the manfiest or you did the package change on the filesystem/directory structure?

Comment: @AliNaddaf Yes, I did both. I right clicked on the package name, selected Refactor > Rename... , which gives a warning. In the warning dialog I selected 'Rename package', which to my surprise actually changed the package name in the Manifest file as well.

Comment: Can you do a "gradle clean" and then grep for the old ID to see if there is anywhere else it can be found?

Comment: @AliNaddaf I honestly do not know what fixed it. I came back from the weekend, and now the app is installing as the new ID. Anyway, thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The emulator is caching this stuff. It need to be cleaned some how may be re-creating the emulator.